# How to set up an Amazon S3 bucket in secure way to serve media and static files to django

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-templates

I'm using Amazon S3 to serve my static and media files to my django website. Do I need to Allow Public access in my Amazon S3 bucket or is there any secure way to do this

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?